# Scala lists "var" usage

Tags: scala, tail-recursion

I am still relatively very new to Scala. I was going through the List implementation of Scala, where I saw that a lot of funcitons still use "var" in the implementation. I have been reading how scala is more functional oriented, therefore instead of using "var" should the library not use tail recursion where possible.

For example exsits could be re-written as:

```
@tailrec
def exists[A](f : A => Boolean) : Boolean = this match {
    case Nil => false
    case l:LinearSeq[A]=> if (f(l.head)) true else exists(l.tail,f)
}
```

The reason I ask is as I have being reading a lot of material where it is discouraged to use "var", but I see a lot of that being used in the List implementation.

Thanks!

Comment: Scala recommend minimize state in your programs as it possible. In some cases it may decrease performance. Then you may use mutability with `var`

Answer (score 5):

When you have something like `List`, which is used very often in nearly every Scala program:

1. even a very minor speedup (or slowdown) can have a large cumulative effect;
2. its contributors tend to be ones who know a lot about Scala low-level details (and if some don't, their patches will be reviewed by those who do).

So advice given to people just learning Scala isn't particularly applicable.

For this specific example: `@tailrec` didn't exist until Scala 2.8, this code was probably written earlier (I haven't checked) and there is not sufficiently good reason to rewrite it.

Comment: I once attended a talk about tips and tricks for newcomers. One of the (very reasonable) tips was "always make your case classes final". Odersky was attending the talk and during the Q&A he mentioned that the compiler team sometimes leverages the fact that case classes are not automatically final for some optimizations. In the end, the tip was revised to sound more like "always make your case classes final... unless you know what you are doing." Which is probably a good general advice. As long as you can tell you really know what you are doing. ;)

Comment: A good reason to re-write the code in a functional way is that new Scala users look at the standard library for inspiration.

Comment: @Tim Ok, no good _enough_ (according to the Scala team) reason then :)

Answer (score 4):

The designers of the standard library chose performance over purity.

The main downside is that the standard library is not a good resource for learning about how to write pure functional code.

A secondary downside is that it reduces the incentive for the compiler to optimise pure functional code, because it does not affect the core library.

Answer (score 2):

The blunt reason is usually performance. With the reasoning that local (!) `var`s do not break FP and still allow concurrency to work.

In this case, the reason probably is another. The implementation works also for non-Lists, only using the `IterableOnce` methods.